# Вывод категорий из базы посредством счётчика FOR и численного массива.

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Пытаюсь вывести категории на главную страницу. Выводятся только числа счётчика. Что здесь не так?

```
function showcat() {
    $str="SELECT * FROM cat";
    $rs=mysql_query($str);
    $arr=mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_NUM);
    $num=mysql_num_rows($rs);
    for($i=1; $i<= $num; $i++) {
        echo $i;
        echo $arr[$i];          
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что вы получаете только одну строку результата. Чтобы получить все строки - нужно делать это в цикле.

```
function showcat() {
    $str="SELECT * FROM cat";
    $rs=mysql_query($str);
    if ( !($rs && mysql_num_rows($rs)) ) return;
    $i = 1;
    while( $arr=mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_NUM) ) {
         echo $i++; //
         print_r($arr); // массив $arr содержит одну строку результата
    }
}
```